# Bluetooth adapter not found Ubuntu 19

Tags: bluetooth

Have tried everything in forums including (but probably not limited to):

1. Turning on and off bluetooth in BIOS
2. Checking for a block in rfkill (note NO hci device shows whatsoever with rfkill)
3. Checking to ensure bluetooth service is running (below output)
4. Installing / upgrading bluez (have tried both 5.50 and 5.51)
5. Additional firmware for the integrated Wifi / Bluetooth card (intel AX200) - Note this card required me to add a ucode file to /lib/firmware from intel's website just to get the Wifi working - bluetooth still not on.
6. Upgrading the kernel (I've run everything starting at 5.0 - 5.3.6.  Note that the Intel AX200 says it requires 5.1+).

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
[ 1015.995530] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[ 1015.995543] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 1015.995546] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 1015.995547] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 1015.995548] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 1775.506820] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 1775.506821] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 1775.506825] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 2100.910497] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 2100.910502] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 2100.910506] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

```
lspci -nnk| grep "blue"
(nothing returned)

hciconfig
(nothing returned)
```

```
$ rfkill 
ID TYPE DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan phy0   unblocked unblocked

hcitool scan
Device is not available: No such device

sudo service bluetooth status
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-10-13 21:29:29 PDT; 11h ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 16822 (bluetoothd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 2.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─16822 /usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd

bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this matter @user2313135 ? I have a similar problem with an Intel Wireless-AC 9560 (WiFi + Bluetooth) chip, that I cannot get to work.